# JOOQ EXISTS clause with plain SQL

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I'm building the WHERE clause of a JOOQ query. Some conditions use EXISTS, and I'd like to provide the sub-query as plain SQL, because they are long-winded expressed with JOOQ. eg.

```
select 1 from jsonb_array_elements(resource->'name') as t1,
  jsonb_array_elements_text(t1.value->'given') as t2
where t2.value like ?
```

However DSL.exists() accepts only Select type as parameter, and no matter which DSL.select...() method I use, it will wrap my SQL snippet with another select.

```
DSL.exists(DSL.selectFrom(DSL.sql(...)))
```

And the query will be like:

```
... where exists (select * from (select 1 from ...
```

Is there a way to avoid the unneeded wrapper select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a plain SQL condition like this:

```
Condition condition = DSL.condition("exists (<your select here>)");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you put the SQL in DSL.sql?

You can pass the SQL string directly to selectFrom:

```
DSL.exists(DSL.selectFrom(...))
```

Then you don't get this wrapper select.

Comment: Later I removed it, but the selectFrom still creates the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

For now all I could do was to chop the SQL to clauses. I would still be interested in a different solution.

```
return DSL.exists(DSL.selectOne().from(
    "jsonb_array_elements(resource->'name') as t1," +
    " jsonb_array_elements_text(t1.value->'given') as t2"
).where(
    "t2.value like ?", pattern)
);
```